# Add "%" percentage to kibana canvas metric

Tags: kibana

I am using a metric element and I want to add a percentage "%" label, so it looks like 45% for example, this is its default code expression

```
filters
| essql 
  query="SELECT round(cup * 100) as cup_percentage FROM \"demodata\" order by created_at desc limit 1"
| math "cup_percentage"
| metric "" 
  metricFont={font family="'Open Sans', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif" size=48 align="center" color="#000000" weight="normal" underline=false italic=false} 
  labelFont={font family="'Open Sans', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif" size=14 align="right" color="#000000" weight="normal" underline=false italic=false}
| render css=".canvasRenderEl {

}"
```

So I have seen in some examples and documentation I have to use markdown function, more or less like this:

```
| markdown {getCell "cup_percentage" row=0} "%"
```

But I have tried to plug it in without luck so far, it doesnt find the cup_percentage column, but the query should be correct

Answer (score 0):

I found that using the formatnumber method worked out for me:

```
filters
| essql 
  query="SELECT round(cup * 100) as cup_percentage FROM \"demodata\" order by created_at desc limit 1"
| math "cup_percentage"
| formatnumber format="0.0%"
| metric "" 
  metricFont={font family="'Open Sans', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif" size=48 align="center" color="#000000" weight="normal" underline=false italic=false} 
  labelFont={font family="'Open Sans', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif" size=14 align="right" color="#000000" weight="normal" underline=false italic=false}
| render css=".canvasRenderEl {

}"
```